# Is there a single word for "client of a trainer"

Tags: word-request

How a person could be called with one word when we reference to him as a client of a trainer. (gym trainer).

Comment: yes, it's a `trainee`

Comment: Yes that was my idea too, but trainee doesn't mean newbie? greenhorn?

Comment: Why not just "client"?

Comment: I am using client now, but I find client meaning too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word is [*trainee*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=40&safe=active&site=&source=hp&q=define+trainee) as stated in existing comments.

You added a comment asking if trainee meant a newbie or greenhorn.  No, it does not.
A person can be skilled and trained to a certain level in any activity but is still a trainee while trying to attain a higher level.
To use your example: someone skilled in gymnastics and competing at local level can be in training - a trainee - for national level.